# How to save list of objects using bulk_update method in Django?

Tags: django, performance, orm

I have a loop iterating over objects and adding them to the list

```
for note in notes:
             old_note = Note(
                        user_id=note['id']),
                        author=note['author'],         
                    )
                    existing_notes.append(old_note)
 Worklog.objects.bulk_update(
                existing_notes,
                [
                    'user_id',
                    'author',
                ],
                batch_size=1000)
```

but it's not working as i wish it should. When i run my script with celery task in django , it's kinda crashing. PLease help guys , if any is capable to show my mistake.
My final goal is to add all objects i need into list and update them in database at once, cause i have really a lot of data

Comment: This is not the complete code, right? Where is your existing_nodes list created? Can you post the parts of your code where existing_notes is instantiated?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Existing nodes is only the empty list, where i put objects , and then try to update all of them with bulk update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating new objects, you should use `bulk_create` instead of `bulk_update`.

`bulk_update` will try to find and update existing objects, but when you create an object through instantiating it's class, like you do with `Note(...)`, it does not get saved to the database yet. So that's why you are getting errors.

Also, you are using conflicting Models. You create a list of `Notes`, but try to update them through `Worklog`.
Use either `Note` or `Worklog` for both of them.

Your updated code should look like this:

```
for note in notes:
             old_note = Note(
                        user_id=note['id']),
                        author=note['author'],         
                    )
                    existing_notes.append(old_note)

 Note.objects.bulk_create(
                existing_notes,
                batch_size=1000)
```

Comment: Thank you Nico)  I succeed with bulk create method, but cant use update method. How can i update a lot of objects in database at once with list?

Comment: That depends on the context. Generally speaking, make sure the objects you are updating exist in the database, make sure you don't update their primary key, and make sure you pass the correct fields to the `bulk_update` method.


I advise you to check out the docs on bulk_update for an example:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update

Comment: I checked docs, checked all the fields but my script is not updating objects in database. I'm confused about one thing in doc , its been said that "the method doesn't call post save method" , does it mean i can't update objects in database with bulk_update method??? I pass into list correct data , and pass it to bulk_update method but it somehow doesnt update objects in db.

Comment: Is bulk_update method works in similar manner? If i just change bulk_create in your edited example, to bulk _update will it work ?

Answer (score 0):

lets say if you have a model object Book with a name field,
like:

**In models**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True)
```

Then if you have a list of names to create the books:

```
book_list = [{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"},{"name":"C"}]
```

Then all you've got to do is pass this list(list of dictionaries) into the  Book() to create a list of Book objects first.
Then the final step is to save those objects to database using

```
Book.objects.bulk_create(list of objects here)
```

It looks like:

```
objects = [] #list for Book objects

new_object = [] #list for new object to add to Book objects

for i in booklist:  #'booklist' is the list of bookname dictionaries
`new_object = Book(name = i['name']) #book objects with each name in` 


booklist
objects.append(new_object) #list of Book objects

#saving list of book objects created in the for loop
Book.objects.bulk_create(objects)
```